# 400 Bad Request in Curl

Tags: c#, curl, http-status-code-400, libcurl.net

For several days, I have been trying to post to a server. But I get a bad request error which is:

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Server: cloudflare-nginx
Date: Sat, 13 Oct 2012 14:25:32 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 522
Connection: close

<html>
<head><title>400 Bad Request</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>400 Bad Request</h1></center>
<hr><center>cloudflare-nginx</center>
</body>
</html>
<!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->
<!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->
<!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->
<!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->
<!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->
<!-- a pad
```

---

my code is here (*I used **libcurl.net** on c#*)

```cs
Curl.GlobalInit((int)CURLinitFlag.CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);
Thread.Sleep(400);
try
{
    var curl = new Easy();

    Easy.WriteFunction wf = new Easy.WriteFunction(OnWriteData);

    curl.SetOpt(CURLoption.CURLOPT_URL, webpage);
    curl.SetOpt(CURLoption.CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
    curl.SetOpt(CURLoption.CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, "100");
    curl.SetOpt(CURLoption.CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false);

    Slist sl = new Slist();

    sl.Append(String.Format("POST {0} HTTP/1.1\r\n\r\n", (new Uri(oyy.sayfa).PathAndQuery)));
    sl.Append(String.Format("Host: {0}", hostname ));
    sl.Append(String.Format("{0}", "Connection: keep-alive"));
    sl.Append(String.Format("Content-Length: {0}", param.Length));
    sl.Append(String.Format("Origin: {0}", originname));
    sl.Append(String.Format("{0}", "X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest"));
    sl.Append(String.Format("User-Agent: {0}",  "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/22.0.1229.94 Safari/537.4")); 

    sl.Append(String.Format("{0}", "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"));
    sl.Append(String.Format("{0}", "Accept: */*"));
    sl.Append(String.Format("Referer: {0}",referans)); 
    sl.Append(String.Format("{0}", "Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch"));
    sl.Append(String.Format("{0}", "Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8"));
    sl.Append(String.Format("{0}", "Accept-Charset: utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3*/"));
    sl.Append("\r\n\r\n");

    curl.SetOpt(CURLoption.CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, sl); 

    curl.SetOpt(CURLoption.CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, CookieFile);
    curl.SetOpt(CURLoption.CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, CookieFile);
    curl.SetOpt(CURLoption.CURLOPT_COOKIE, "cokieee");
     curl.SetOpt(CURLoption.CURLOPT_PROXY, "http://127.0.0.1:9050");
    curl.SetOpt(CURLoption.CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, CURLproxyType.CURLPROXY_SOCKS5);
    curl.SetOpt(CURLoption.CURLOPT_VERBOSE, false);
    curl.SetOpt(CURLoption.CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, wf);

    curl.Perform();
    curl.Cleanup();
    curl.GlobalCleanup(); 

    string result = sourceContent.ToString();

----------


public Int32 OnWriteData(Byte[] buf, Int32 size, Int32 nmemb, Object extraData)
{
  string aa = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buf);
  this.sourceContent.Append(aa + " ");
  return size * nmemb;
}
```

I think that problem is based on `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER`. I think that `sl` (*`SList`*) is not true or I've missed to add something. All information what I have above.

Comment: Have you inspected the actual request being sent by a tool such as Fiddler or Wireshark? Fiddler: http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/ and Wireshark: http://www.wireshark.org/

Comment: I did it but I cant read anything because post values are encoded. I got some kind of different characters such as square

Comment: I know Fiddler can encode and decode a lot of common request.

Comment: fiddler cant get any post values :) here is picture of fiddler. http://img571.imageshack.us/img571/7092/5b20a23e2c3a428fa5230e4.png as you see, there is no info about my post

Comment: Yea I see. Just to help debug change url just to be port 80 and try it again with fiddler. The next item is to not use the loopback address. I have had some issues with the loopback and non-http ports in the past using fiddler.

Comment: and here on wireshark, http://img835.imageshack.us/img835/4387/24c0a5d519934ccd8d037d9.png

Comment: I cant change the port is 9050. Because I use tor as proxy. and I commented proxy codes but result is same for fiddler

Comment: Do you know what encoding is being used? That does seem standard and I bet that is the culprit of your issue.

Comment: actually I dont know why is encoded. maybe it occours from curl. you see all code and there is not any reason to be encoded

Answer (score 1):

According to the libcurl.net documentation, it says to not add CRLF to your headers that you pass to `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER` since libcurl.net already adds CRLF with the request. You may be having an issue with the server not correctly picking up some of your header values. Also, don't add the request-line to your headers containing POST or GET. See below for an excerpt from the documentation:

> The headers included in the Slist must not be CRLF-terminated, because
> curl adds CRLF after each header item. Failure to comply with this
> will result in strange bugs because the server will most likely ignore
> part of the headers you specified.
>
> The first line in a request
> (usually containing a GET or POST) is not a header and cannot be
> replaced using this option. Only the lines following the request-line
> are headers.